# PyQt5; problem with threading using QRunnable and QThreadPool

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread, qrunnable

It seems that I have a problem with running threads in my application as follows:
in my MainForm class I have:

```
.
.
self.threadPool = QtCore.QThreadPool()
self.threadPool.setMaxThreadCount(4)
.
.
def openFileFcn(self):
worker = **Worker**(self, **self.ImageViewer.showImages**, self.files)
self.threadPool.start(worker)
```

where **Worker** is a wrapper QRunnable defined as:

```
class Worker(QtCore.QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        QtCore.QRunnable.__init__(self)
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def run(self) -> None:
        self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
```

and **self.ImageViewer.showImages** refers to the below section of the ImageViewer class:

```
    def loadImg(self, file):
        tabName = str()
        if len(file) > 15: tabName = file[0:13] + "..."

        widget = ImageViewer()
        localPath = os.path.abspath(file)
        localPath = QtCore.QDir().filePath(localPath)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(localPath)
        widget.setImage(pixmap)
        self.tabwidget.addTab(widget, self.mainFormHandle.sharedData.imgIcon, tabName)
        self.tabwidget.setCurrentIndex(self.tabwidget.currentIndex() + 1)

    def **showImages**(self, files):
        files = [file.lower() for file in files]
        for file in files:
            self.loadImg(file)
```

Nothing much happens when I run this code. It just freezes and after a while the application closes with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409). What do you suggest to be the cause?

Comment: a little correction: where I write "and self.ImageViewer.showImages refers to the below section of the ImageViewer class:" I mean: "and self.ImageViewer.showImages refers to the below section of the TabArea class"

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you are trying to create widgets from another thread than the main thread. You can only create widgets from the main thread but since `loadImg()` creates several widgets, calling it from the thread pool crashes your application. One way to get around this is to split `loadImg()` into two methods, one method that loads the pixmaps, and another one that creates the `ImageViewer`s and adds the tabs. The first one can then be moved to the thread pool, and you can use a signal to automatically call the second one every time a pixmap is loaded. For example:

```
class TabArea(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    pixmap_loaded = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, QtGui.QPixmap)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        self.pixmap_loaded.connect(self.addTab)

    def loadImg(self, file):
        localPath = os.path.abspath(file)
        localPath = QtCore.QDir().filePath(localPath)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(localPath)
        # emit pixmap and file name
        self.pixmap_loaded.emit(file, pixmap)

    def addTab(self, file, pixmap):
        tabName = str()
        if len(file) > 15: tabName = file[0:13] + "..."
        widget = ImageViewer()
        widget.setImage(pixmap)
        self.tabwidget.addTab(widget, self.mainFormHandle.sharedData.imgIcon, tabName)
        self.tabwidget.setCurrentIndex(self.tabwidget.currentIndex() + 1)

    def showImages(self, files):
        files = [file.lower() for file in files]
        for file in files:
            self.loadImg(file)
```